# Android - Replacing contact photos using local image files programmatically

Tags: android, android-contacts

Most of you should be aware of this on going issue with Android:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=49e2b1adea1aa11c&hl=en

Basically, when you synced with GMail Contacts, the contact photos will be replaced with the low resolution 96x96 pixel resolutions that are stored in the GMail Contacts.

My question, how easy is it to create an Android application that does this:

- Start the application
- Click the "Replace" button
- Then the application will search all image files in folder /sdcard/ContactPhotos
- For each matching image file name with ", .png", the application will replace the contact photo with that image file
- Process until finished
- Done

The idea of this application, user could easily replace all contact photos using locally stored high resolution image files, in one go.

So, is this possible? And what's your take on this?

Does this kind of application need root permission?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, and wouldn't need root access. The problem is going to be that the user would need to properly name all the images first, consistently, accurately, and in a unique manner. For example, if you had three contacts named John Rodeo, then the naming convention of `JohnRodeo.png` or `Rodeo_John.png` would not work, as you could not have three images with the same name. Even if there was no duplication of data, you would need to make sure all names followed a consistent naming scheme (`lastname_firstname.png` for example). Of course, you could also add an algorithm to search filenames for likely variations and not have to worry about exact consistency.

It's certainly a feasible idea, but it would be much easier if Facebook would kiss and make up with Google already, and just play nice with the Contacts API. :/

Comment: Naming the file is not really a problem. User needs only to do it once. And for multiple contact with same names, well, you can add phone number into it as additional option. Oh by the way, this is not about Facebook contact sync, especially because not all contacts are on Facebook. This is mainly to workaround the low resolution contact photos after synced with GMail Contacts.